# Why is [[ "$input" == name1* || name2* ]] never false?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, xargs

I'm a little befuddled with a script I've been writing - and would appreciate some help!
This is one of those cases where each command seems to work fine on their own, but not so when put together into a script.
Here's a gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
input=$1

single_func () {
   command "$input"
}

multi_func () {
   xargs < $input -n 1 single_func
}

if [[ "$input" == name1* || name2* ]];
then
   single_func
elif [[  -f "$input" ]];
then
   multi_func
else
   echo "exiting"
   exit
fi
```

The idea here is - if the script is invoked with ./script.sh input, if will run if the input starts with name1 or name2, using single_func. If the input provided doesn't start with name1 or name2, and is a file containing a list of items, elif will run (reason for -f) using multi_fuc, which is just single_func running with xarg on the provided file.
The 'single_func' component runs on the command line fine on its own (command "input"), and the 'multi_func' component runs fine with a test file (xargs < testfile.txt -n 1 ./single_func.sh). But when I put them together as above and try to run them together, only the first 'if' part works correctly. When provided with a file or some nonsense line not containing name1 or name2, the script simply exits without returning anything.
For the curious, I'm running entrez direct commands within the single_func block.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[[ a = b || c ]]` is not `[[ a = b || a = c ]]`. This is not uniquely or specifically a bash mistake -- people make this in _every_ language; it's just like writing `if foo == "bar" or "baz"` in Python, which is _also_ always true.

Comment: BTW, consider using `bash -x yourscript` to trace execution, and maybe modify the script to set `PS4=':$LINENO+'` or similar so xtrace logs show which line execution is at. Much easier to write an accurately descriptive question when you know what's going on.

Comment: I never knew about bash -x. This is amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write:

```
if [[ "$input" = name1* || "$input" = name2* ]]; then
```

Otherwise, the right-hand side of your `||` tests whether `name2*` is a non-empty string, which it always unconditionally is, making the statement always true.

If you don't want to repeat yourself (and your real use case is complex enough you can't just change it to `if [[ "$input" = name[12]* ]]`), use a `case` statement instead:

```
case $input in
  name1*|name2*)  echo "Either name1 or name2 prefix found";;
  *)              echo "Neither prefix found";;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like fixing the if [[]] content revealed another thing I did wrong - the second function 'multi_func' was supposed to run xarg on the first function 'single_func'. The goal was to use the single_func commands on a provided file, line by line. However, xargs isn't able to pull in shell functions, it turns out. Would you have a recommendation here? Or should this be a separate search/question?

Comment: @phigeon you can export shell functions -- `yourfunc() { echo "Doing stuff to $item"; }; export -f yourfunc` -- and then have xargs start a new copy of bash to import and run the function (`xargs bash -c 'for item; do yourfunc "$item"; done' _`). But it should indeed be a separate question.

Comment: ...that said, I don't _recommend_ using xargs here at all unless you have an _extremely_ good reason. Having xargs start a bunch of new shells to all run a function that's already in-process is going to be _much_ slower than avoiding it outright by using a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop.